# Ajax wordpress tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I was looking for tabs with loading content and refresh page after clicking in the tabs button I have found this code in webdeveloper.com by Mitya
it works fine out WordPress but when I put it in my custom theme file it didn't work I don't know why

Question: how I can make it work with WordPress ?

Here is the code

```html
   
<!--Tabs Area -->
<script type="text/javascript">

function startAjax() { //appropriate to browser being used
    var xmlHttpObj;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlHttpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        try { xmlHttpObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
        catch (e) {
            try { xmlHttpObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
            catch (e) { xmlHttpObj = false; }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttpObj;
}
gateway = startAjax();

function getTabContent(tabNum, afterAjaxResponse) {
 if (!afterAjaxResponse) {
     if (!gateway) {
      alert('Your browser does not support XMLHTTP');
      return;
     } else {
         gateway.open('GET', 'getTabContent.php?tabNum='+tabNum, true);
         gateway.onreadystatechange = function() { getTabContent(null, true); }
         gateway.send(null);
     }
 } else if (gateway.readyState == 4 && gateway.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById('tabsUnder').innerHTML = gateway.responseText;
 }
}

window.onload = function() {
 
 getTabContent(1);
 
 var tabsHouser = document.getElementById('tabs');
 var tabs = tabsHouser.getElementsByTagName('li');
 tabsHouser.onclick = function(e) {
  var clickedElement = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
  if (clickedElement.id.match(/^tab\d{1}$/)) {
   var clickedTabNum = clickedElement.id.substr(clickedElement.id.length-1, 1);
   for(var k=0; k<tabs.length; k++) tabs[k].className = '';
   clickedElement.className = 'on';
   getTabContent(clickedTabNum);
  }
 }
 
}

</script>

<ul id="tabs">
 <li class='on' id='tab1'>tab1</li>
 <li id='tab2'>tab2</li>
 <li id='tab3'>tab3</li>
 <li id='tab4'>tab4</li>
 <li id='tab5'>tab5</li>
</ul>
<div id="tabsUnder"></div>
              <?php get_template_part( 'getTabContent' ); ?>                      
<!--End Tabs Content Area-->
```

getTabContent.php code :

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['tabNum'])) {
    switch($_GET['tabNum']) {
 case 1: echo "this is the content for the <b>first</b> tab"; break;
 case 2: echo "this is the content for the <b>second</b> tab"; break;
 case 3: echo "this is the content for the <b>third</b> tab"; break;
 case 4: echo "this is the content for the <b>fourth</b> tab"; break;
 case 5: echo "this is the content for the <b>fifth</b> tab"; break;
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin in wordpress and can generate shortcode wherever you want to place it. For ajax either you can use the wordpress built-in admin ajax or you can develop your own ajax and can place it inside your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Since you meantioned a custom theme,
make sure you have jQuery enqueued in functions.php
you should see something like :

```
<?php
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/amazing_script.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

and keep in mind that it's json2 for AJAX calls